# PostgreSQL (pgAdmin) and cross-site cookie warnings

Tags: javascript, python, django, cookies, pgadmin

I'm using python 3.7.4, django 3.0.6, javascript, Postgres 12.3.1. When my page loads on the console there are these warnings:

```
Cookie “PGADMIN_KEY” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “http://127.0.0.1:8000/lists/list-name/” because the scheme does not match. list-name
Cookie “PGADMIN_LANGUAGE” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “http://127.0.0.1:8000/lists/list-name/” because the scheme does not match. list-name
Cookie “PGADMIN_KEY” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “http://127.0.0.1:8000/lists/list-name/” because the scheme does not match. list-name
Cookie “PGADMIN_LANGUAGE” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “http://127.0.0.1:8000/lists/list-name/” because the scheme does not match. list-name
Cookie “PGADMIN_KEY” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/lists/js/lists.js” because the scheme does not match. lists.js
Cookie “PGADMIN_LANGUAGE” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/lists/js/lists.js” because the scheme does not match. lists.js
Cookie “PGADMIN_KEY” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “http://127.0.0.1:8000/jsi18n/” because the scheme does not match. jsi18n
Cookie “PGADMIN_LANGUAGE” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “http://127.0.0.1:8000/jsi18n/” because the scheme does not match. jsi18n
Cookie “PGADMIN_KEY” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/common.js” because the scheme does not match. common.js
Cookie “PGADMIN_LANGUAGE” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/common.js” because the scheme does not match. common.js
Cookie “PGADMIN_KEY” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/icons/favicon.png” because the scheme does not match. favicon.png
Cookie “PGADMIN_LANGUAGE” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/icons/favicon.png” because the scheme does not match. favicon.png
```

​They should come from the [new policy about cookies](https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/developers-get-ready-for-new.html). The problem is `PGADMIN_KEY` and `PGADMIN_LANGUAGE` are cookies of PGAdmin (PostgreSQL) and I don't use them explicitly (I mean evidently the database himself use them but in my code they don't appear) so how can I solve this problem?

- It is a bug of PGAdmin and all I can do is to wait for a new version of PGAdmin where this bug is fixed?
- I should explicitly declare them in my code (where???) with `SameSite=none; Secure` parameters?
- other?

Thank you for your help.

PS

I did another question related and someone in a deleted comment (sigh don't delete comments please) said something like `/localhost/` is counted like different from `/127.0.0.1:8000/`. I don't know if this can help me

Comment: The cookie names speak for themselves. They come from the pgAdmin program, which I assume is what you are running when you get the messages. pgAdmin is a third party application and is not Postgres. These cookies are not coming from Postgres.

Comment: Ah, ok thank you for the clarification. I thinked they were the same thing (I'm inexpert). But the problem stay. It is a pgadmin bug? So I should wait for a new version?

Comment: I have no idea. You could file an issue here:https://redmine.postgresql.org/projects/pgadmin4/issues. You will need to sign up for a community account to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved upgrading to the last version of pgAdmin (the one included in PostgreSQL is not the last) AND deleting the cookies stored in the cache.